# How to convert Ansible task name value to upper case?

Tags: ansible

How to convert the Ansible task name value to an upper case like currently it's

```yaml
- name: Test
```

I want output show `TEST`.

I have tried

```yaml
-name: {{ "test" | upper }}
```

it not worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce since a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: "{{ 'test' | upper }}"
    debug:
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [TEST] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Hello world!
```

**Further Documentation**

- [`debug` module – Print statements during execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html)
- [When to quote variables (a YAML gotcha)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#when-to-quote-variables-a-yaml-gotcha)

  > *If you start a value with `{{ foo }}`, you must quote the whole expression to create valid YAML syntax. If you do not quote the whole expression, the YAML parser cannot interpret the syntax ...*

Comment: For a first time Ansible user, it could be a bit difficult to determine whether TEST is supposed to be in capitals or not, since TASK is also in caps, and the hello world message is not :)

Comment: @KevinC, I was ones a first time Ansible user too. And I found the first steps also very difficult and confusing. But I've realized that if I read the manuals and with minimal examples where I can focus on the functionality and play around with I can gain deep insights fast. That what this example and the links are for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am able to get result from method you provided , Seems "" wont work in that case, as you mentioned single quote worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the follwing with ansible-playbook core 2.14.2 and jinja version 3.1.2. It works with upper filter.

playbook:

```
- name: Test debug upper filter
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="this sentence should be in lower but {{ 'this sentence should be in upper' | upper }}"
```

Output:

```
ok: [localmachine] => {
    "msg": "this sentence should be in lower but THIS SENTENCE SHOULD BE IN UPPER" }
```

Can you post what you have tried and if the above i posted works for you?

Comment: Thanks for solution, I tried single quote as per your suggestion and worked   -name: {{ 'test' | upper }}

Comment: no @SRE. if my post solved your problem, feel free to mark it as a solution :)